# Fate tag redux: The Archive Trawl Blues

Tags: discussion, tags, fate

So, I'm doing research for a behavioral meta question about answering Fate questions, and that means slogging through Fate posts on the site for examples and precedents. *ALL* of the Fate posts.

I can track down about a dozen *Dungeons & Dragons* tags which are actually used. If I went through them, I'd feel like I'd probably seen every D&D-related post on site. I'll have waded through something like 3,000 posts and may soon perish of Acute Alignment Poisoning (tell your friends about AAP; the life you save may be your own), but I'll feel like I got a pretty complete grasp of the site's D&D catalogue.

In order to do the same for Fate, I have to [learn the name of every individual game ever produced using the Fate engine](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/index.php?filters=0_0_0_44284) (and apparently there are debates about that; for example, the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FATE_(role-playing_game_system)#RPGs_based_on_Fate) which sites [this post](http://www.faterpg.com/2011/fate-and-its-branches/) as its source ignores the post's caveats). It doesn't seem like I could *ever* confident that I'd seen most of RPG.SE's Fate game posts.

Now, perhaps my comparison is faulty, and I should be looking at d20 System tags instead of D&D tags. But I don't see [dnd-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-4e) questions getting answered with [call-of-cthulhu-d20](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-cthulhu-d20) rules nearly so often as I see [dresden-files](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dresden-files) questions getting [spirit-of-the-century](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spirit-of-the-century) answers. So if my comparison is faulty, there's a behavioral issue that needs to be addressed about Fate answers and I'll open a meta question about that.

Although the [fate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate) tag was never very comprehensive, [this meta discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2942/4398) leaves me with the impression that I now can't even *hope* for a single tag, or a small group of tags (and let me point out that under the circumstances D&D's round dozen tags are a small number, since they feel comprehensive), that'll let me feel like I can track down all the Fate questions. Instead I have to round them up tag after tag after tag after interminal guesswork-discovered tag and just hope not to go mad over the astonishing number of duplicates that are wasting my time and brain.

Is this correct? Am I missing a search function? Am I misinterpreting that meta discussion?
Or should I just suck it up and accept that this is a necessary casualty of the tagging policy?

Comment: Note: the behavior I'm researching can potentially be found in *any* Fate answer, whether the question is specific to a game/system/setting or universal to the Fate engine, because it's about the way we approach answering questions about this engine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We should keep a list of the various Fate systems within the [fate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate) tag's wiki.

In [that meta discussion you mentioned](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2942/4398) I expressed my stance that everyone asking a Fate question should always use the system tag for the system they're using. We *know* that using the [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) tag when asking a [dnd-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-4e) question isn't very helpful and I'm sure similar issues exist in Fate systems, but that leaves us having to trawl through all the different Fate system tags to find all the Fate questions. Hence: let's keep track of those systems.

Comment: +1 Good solution.

Comment: This seems like a legit solution for the [tag:dungeons-and-dragons] and [tag:d20] tags as well. Oh wait, it's already there on D&D

Comment: As I said in that discussion, I don't think we should tag Fate questions with [fate] for convenience since it's misleading and harms the quality of the answers, but yes, a catalogue in the description of the [fate] tag is very nearly a necessity. If we're going to say "don't use [fate] to tag every Fate game question", we need a guide for what tags *should* be used!

Answer (score 5):

Fate-related tags that we have, in descending order of use as of right now:

- [dresden-files](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dresden-files)
- [fate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate)
- [fate-core](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-core)
- [aspects](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aspects)*
- [diaspora](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diaspora)
- [stress](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stress)*
- [fate-accelerated](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-accelerated)
- [spirit-of-the-century](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spirit-of-the-century)
- [fudge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fudge)*
- [legends-of-anglerre](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legends-of-anglerre)
- [thresholds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thresholds) (only one question, may disappear)

<sup>* *Denotes a tag that's not strictly Fate-only, but in practice is full of Fate questions.*</sup>

This set of tags isn't a complete representation of Fate-based games, of course, but it's will get you nearly every question we have about Fate-based games. (It's a useful place to start from to fill out the [fate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate) tag's wiki and tag-usage guide, too.) New tags are added infrequently, and can be caught by keeping an eye on the front page for new questions.

You can [query that entire Fate-based game tag set](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dresden-files+or+fate+or+fate-core+or+aspects+or+diaspora+or+stress+or+fate-accelerated+or+spirit-of-the-century+or+fudge+or+legends-of-anglerre+or+thresholds) by clicking that link, or by copying and pasting this search into the search form:

```
[dresden-files] or [fate] or [fate-core] or [aspects] or [diaspora] or [stress] or [fate-accelerated] or [spirit-of-the-century] or [fudge] or [legends-of-anglerre] or [thresholds]
```

For a full list of Fate-based games beyond what we have tags and questions for, [the RPGGeek database entry for the Fate family of RPGs](http://rpggeek.com/rpgsystem/577/fate) is one of the most maintained references.