# gurps and gurps-4e tagging the same post

Tags: discussion, tags

My understanding is that generic system tags like [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) or [fate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate) should not be used if a more specific tag like [dnd-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-4e) or [dresden-files](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dresden-files) is also applicable.

For reference: [How Should We Tag D&D Versions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2760/4398), [Does the [system-agnostic] tag conflict with system specific tags?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3024/4398), [Cross-system Fate tag protocol](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2942/4398), and [Fate tag redux: The Archive Trawl Blues](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2997/4398).

I've been seeing a lot of posts tagged both [gurps](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps) and [gurps-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps-4e) lately. I know nothing about GURPS, but the tag wikis seem to say that [gurps](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps) is to [gurps-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps-4e) as [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) is to [dnd-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-4e).

So: Do we need to excise [gurps](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps) from [these nine posts](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps+gurps-4e), and help people avoid double-tagging in the future?

Answer (score 4):

Not really.  In GURPS, like Call of Cthulhu and many other non-D&D games, there's not a lot of change from version to version.  For rules wonks, answering for D&D 1e vs 2e vs 3e vs 4e is a completely different thing.  For many of these other games, it's a lot more correct to say "I have a GURPS question...  It's 4e if it matters, but it's not likely it will."   And that's what that tag combo is saying.  We don't have federal reporting standards dictating everyone disclose their exact rules edition, the point is to scope it's domain to get the right people to answer in the desired scope and to facilitate future find ability within that scope - they are doing that fine and I fail to see any bad effect justifying mass intervention in those questions.