# Fixing umbrella tag of mutants-and-masterminds

Tags: discussion, tags, editing, game-systems

I recently noticed that [mutants-and-masterminds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutants-and-masterminds) was largely being used in conjunction with either the [mutants-and-masterminds-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutants-and-masterminds-2e) or [mutants-and-masterminds-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutants-and-masterminds-3e) tags, but not discussing the overarching system. I changed the tag info and description, but noting that I do plan, once I'm home from work, to quickly go in and fix tags. Two questions:

1. Should I space out the edits so as to not accidentally dominate the front page?
2. There are currently no questions tagged for 1e that I noticed. I assume it's probably best to not create one until we need it, and to suggest on the tag usage to just use the umbrella one should there be such a question, and we can fix it in post?

I guess third question:

3. For questions asking about the difference between two editions, should those two edition tags be used, and not the umbrella tag?

Comment: I imagine a good handful of the “generic tag” questions are actually 1e questions, but I don’t know enough about the system to check that.

Comment: {nods} I'm familiar with all three, so I guess that will be something to address tonight, although [Do we need more Mutants and masterminds edition tags?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/do-we-need-more-mutants-and-masterminds-edition-tags) suggests that there weren't many 1E questions at the time of that question.

Comment: To answer (1) real quick, I did five per day on my recent retagging project.

Comment: Just for readers' context, the [mutants-and-masterminds] tag has 55 questions in it. So it's not a huuuuge project Sean's talking about, but it's (IMO) a large enough group of questions that it's worth making an improvement. Thank for noticing and bringing this up, Sean =)

Answer (score 7):

Generally yes edits should be spaced out to avoid overwhelming the front page, and typically questions asking about the differences between two editions have been tagged [edition-comparison](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edition-comparison) plus the two editions concerned.

---

This question seems to be jumping the gun however. The first question we ask about this shouldn't be “How do I handle this restructure?” but instead “*Should* we restructure Mutants & Masterminds's tags, and should we do it like this?” and as far as I can tell that step got skipped completely.

Our Dungeons & Dragons tags have some special handling to use the [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) tag only to discuss the system broadly and not for questions about specific editions, but that's not the default way to handle things, only the most visible. It's the rule we chose to apply to D&D's tags to help us keep things manageable in its expansive landscape, and other systems might have similar tagging rules applied if they need them.

The default way we handle system tags is the default for all tags, “do whatever seems right”, which has shown up in a few past discussions about different systems:

- [Is there a general usage guideline for tagging between editions of the same system where editions are very similar?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7689/is-there-a-general-usage-guideline-for-tagging-between-editions-of-the-same-syst)
- [Should these GURPS questions have an edition-specific system tag?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/should-these-gurps-questions-have-an-edition-specific-system-tag)
- [What is the difference between the [fate] and [fate-core] tags?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6892/what-is-the-difference-between-the-fate-and-fate-core-tags)

That same idea came up in a question about how to structure Mutants & Masterminds in 2014:

- [Do we need more Mutants and masterminds edition tags?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/do-we-need-more-mutants-and-masterminds-edition-tags)

Back in 2014, we had an actual discussion about how we wanted to handle World of Darkness system tags as we looked to reorganise things, which is essentially what I'm suggesting should be happening here first:

- [Clean up tagging for "World of Darkness" related questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4933/clean-up-tagging-for-world-of-darkness-related-questions)

The [mutants-and-masterminds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mutants-and-masterminds) tag contains instructions to handle it like D&D, but as you note, you added those instructions just before asking this meta; they weren't pre-existing. We should be cautious about essentially unilaterally restructuring a tag when that might not even be necessary or wanted by its other players. Granted, you're one of those players, and that counts for a lot, but nobody else has apparently had a chance to weigh in on this yet.

So instead of going straight to “I'm restructuring this, how should I do it”, I suggest the first conversation should be whether it's even helpful to do this so that Mutants & Masterminds players have a chance to comment on how their game should be organised on this site. This will also let people weigh in on your question #2 about what to do regarding a first edition tag.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I ran into the bit in the D&D tag, and assumed that *was* policy.

Comment: That's an understandable mistake. You haven't been the first to make it and won't be the last. I've just now rolled back the instructions you added to the tag wiki. If we do have a discussion about how to restructure the M&M tags and it comes to the decision to handle things this way, we can put those instructions back.

Comment: Similar case: [The Dark Eye](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10021/30306)