# The problem with the [gurps-dungeon-fantasy-rpg] tag wording

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Today I saw a ***Dungeon Fantasy Roleplaying Game*** question (or rather, question spanning both ***GURPS*** and ***DFRPG***), and decided to add the latter tag to it, started typing dungeon-fantasy-roleplaying..., didn't see an autocomplete, realised it's too long, added [dfrpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dfrpg) instead because that's how the community seems to usually refer to it anyway, added a wiki explaining what it is and pointing out that it differs from ***GURPS Dungeon Fantasy*** (and had it approved).

Then I noticed that there have been other DFRPG questions, with a confusing tag [gurps-dungeon-fantasy-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps-dungeon-fantasy-rpg). And now that I know it exists, I think it should be replaced, but was unsure whether to just do it, or bring it up on meta. I asked for advice and was directed here.

## Why It's a Misleading Tag:

**TL;DR:** it mashes together two titles - ***GURPS Dungeon Fantasy*** and the ***Dungeon Fantasy Roleplaying Game***, which are already easy to confuse.

The original ***GURPS Dungeon Fantasy*** line is a series of products meant to be used together with ***GURPS 4th Edition***, requiring the ***Basic Set*** and strongly suggesting having ***Magic***. Functionally it's an *expansion*, a series of supplements.

The ***Dungeon Fantasy Roleplaying Game*** is a standalone boxed set (also available in PDF) that is fully self-contained, and whose rules differ from the main-line ***GURPS*** rule-set (e.g. slams) and have been otherwise streamlined. Officially that is termed ***Powered by GURPS***.

While there is a large level of compatibility between main-line ***GURPS*** and ***DFRPG***, it's still considered 'unsafe' to just assume that a mechanic is the same between the two. In fact, on the official forum, ***DFRPG*** resides on a separate subforum (not a subset of the ***GURPS*** subforum).

(Note: so far only two questions are using the old tag, though there may be more DFRPG questions around already - I only made a quick search. This is why I considered just doing the replacement without bringing it up.)

## The Question

Given the above reasoning for keeping the distinction clear, I would like to completely replace the older tag ([gurps-dungeon-fantasy-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps-dungeon-fantasy-rpg)), and/or leave a wiki warning elaborating that the two are similar but distinct, and asking to use either of the appropriate tags. **Should I just do it, or should I not (and why), or is there an alternative procedures that should be followed?**

Comment: [related meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3396/23970) on tagging GURPS editions; it does mention Dungeon Fantasy in passing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly at least a couple other people found the other wording more meaningful.

I don’t see how “dfrpg” is *less* ambiguous and in fact I’m pretty sure there was a dragon flight rpg at some point... avoid unnecessary abbreviations.  ‘Rpg’ is a safe well understood way to save a lot of characters but in a world full of “d” RPGs probably chill at that point.

I worry you are fixing a theoretical and not a real problem here.  Has anyone actually confused the two?  In the two extant questions?  Doesn’t seem so.

I could see talking about removing the gurps- from the tag so it’s dungeon-fantasy-rpg, which would be more correct and not nearly as ambiguous, but IMO tag meddling should be saved for a real problem.  If you had paused after typing “dungeon-fantasy” the existing tag would have popped.

Tags are an emergent folksonomy by design and intervention in them should be minimized.

Comment: strongly agree that `dfrpg` should *not* be the end result: I had to reread the original post a few times to figure out how Dresden Files RPG and GURPS intersected.

Comment: The argument against DFRPG. I still think it should not start with 'GURPS' since I've seen people confuse DFRPG with GURPS DF, and having a tag that doesn't even reflect the title of the game (which was *very deliberately* made a standalone) is not helping.

Comment: ok, my proposal is to split the tag to dungeon-fantasy-rpg and gurps-dungeon-fantasy (at least one of the questions needs both), delete the dfrpg tag, add tag wikis as appropriate. sound good?

Comment: @mxyzplk Yeah, that's good. Maybe also add a note that DFRPG could mean either SJGames' or Evil Hat's game.

Comment: I will delete the dfrpg tag to get rid of that kind of confusion.

Comment: Also, i'll leave tag-wiki'ing to someone who cares...

Comment: Yeah, we probably shouldn’t have [dfrpg] at all, due to the ambiguity. @vicky_molokh Tags have to mean something specific, as we don’t have 1:many disambiguation like Wikipedia, only 1:1 redirection via a synonym. Lacking any way to decide which DFRPG to grant the tag to, we should have just [dungeon-fantasy-rpg] and [dresden-files-rpg] with no abbreviation synonym.

Comment: OK.  There was also "dungeon-fantasy" as a preexisting tag that was used for gurps-dungeon-fantasy questions (meaning there were already two tags being used correctly...) Anyway, I have created gurps-dungeon-fantasy and dungeon-fantasy-rpg and merged in all the other tags mentioned here.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yeah, I shouldn't've used it, probably. I just don't tend to think of Dresden Files, just as nitsua60 didn't think of Dungeon Fantasy. In retrospect it is an interesting coincidence that I apparently ran into two wiki approvals who seemed to agree with the choice. I'll get back to all of this in more detail (checking whether wikis are OK etc.) tomorrow.