# What is the difference between the [fate] and [fate-core] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, fate

There are three "fate" tags at the moment: [fate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate), [fate-core](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-core) and [fate-accelerated](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-accelerated).

FAE emphasis makes sense, but distinguishing Fate Core from "just Fate" seems redundant:

1. If [fate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate) is supposed to be a "generic" Fate tag, then [fate-core](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-core) or [fate-accelerated](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-accelerated) questions should always include it. Therefore, this tag gives no unique information about the question.
2. Many Fate variations are based on Fate Core. There are no "just Fate" rules, even the FAE is basically a hacked Fate Core.
3. There are many questions (including FAE-related) that randomly have or have not [fate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate) or [fate-core](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-core) tags (or both). The difference between [fate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate) and [fate-core](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-core) doesn't seem to be clear.

Shouldn't we merge [fate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate) with [fate-core](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-core) ?

Related question: [Cross-system Fate tag protocol](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2942/cross-system-fate-tag-protocol)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're a little confused on the relationship of Fate to Fate Core. This is a bit like proposing we merge [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) or [d20](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d20) with [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e).

The Fate RPG stretches back [as far as 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fate_(role-playing_game_system)). It had an original standalone iteration, then was implemented as the foundation in many different games through the years like *Spirit of the Century* and *Dresden Files RPG*. Eventually in 2013 Evil Hat produced a definitive standalone "core" edition of the game, appropriately named *Fate Core*, which consolidated various mechanical improvements that'd been developed so far in its various iterations, and made some further improvements, simplifications, and clarifications of its own. This is just one version of the Fate RPG, you see, and it's now being implemented and improved on in subsequent games, so I expect by the year 2030 we'll see a Fate Core 2.

So, no, we shouldn't merge them.

---

As for how we're tagging these questions:

Questions tagged [fate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate) are asking about issues inherent to all Fate editions. (There are no “just Fate” rules, but that doesn't prevent there from being “just Fate” issues.) Questions tagged [fate-core](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-core) are asking about issues inherent to that specific edition.

These are two different scopes, and a question can reasonably be about just one or the other or both.

There might be some consistency we can work on in how we tag, but that's separate to the merge proposal presented here, and we can talk about that in a separate question.

Comment: Well that might be what [tag:fate] was supposed for. But if you click the [tag:fate] tag now, you will see it is used not like the [tag:dungeons-and-dragons] tag. People use it to tag any Fate-related question. Should we do anything about it?

Comment: That's a separate discussion, I think. At the very least what we shouldn't do about it is merge [fate] with one of its edition tags.

Comment: It's also pertinent to note that our convention for D&D questions to not use the generic tag alongside an edition tag is *specifically* a D&D convention, and not a global rule we expect of every system. With [[tag:gurps]] and [world of darkness](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5001/1204), it's part of the taxonomy that we use the more generic tag alongside an edition tag (currently the only one for GURPS being [[tag:gurps-4e]], whose questions are not always also tagged [[tag:gurps]]), or we just don't care and do it whatever way suits us at the time, and this isn't inherently a problem.

Comment: The “do it whatever way suits us at the time” is the default, yeah. For those who weren't here for it, the only reason D&D gets special treatment is that its tags started to cause problems and needed stronger guidance.