# Use of the rolemaster and rolemaster-rm2 tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Looking at questions tagged rolemaster-rm2, they are all also tagged with the rolemaster tag. This doesn't feel right to me. I'm a little confused as to what the rolemaster tag represents. Is it a general tag similar to the dungeons-and-dragons tag, in which case it shouldn't be used at the same time as a rules-edition specific tag? Alternatively, does the rolemaster tag represent a specific edition of the rules? If this is the case, should the tag wiki be made clearer?

Either way, it looks like the current use of the two tags isn't working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tagging is OK. Things seem to be working properly.

### That tagging rule

You're referencing a rule we have for the D&D tags where we don't use [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) if we're only asking about a specific edition, but that rule is *only* for the D&D tags.

The default is just "tag with whatever makes sense at the time". Questions for [fate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate), [gurps](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps), [rolemaster](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rolemaster) and others frequently get a series tag as well as an edition tag because it makes sense at the time. There's no standardisation there and I'm not aware of any pressing need to establish any.

Apparently that rule for D&D tagging was created [to resolve some problems](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6892/what-is-the-difference-between-the-fate-and-fate-core-tags/6893#comment21139_6893):

> The “do it whatever way suits us at the time” is the default, yeah. For those who weren't here for it, the only reason D&D gets special treatment is that its tags started to cause problems and needed stronger guidance.  – SevenSidedDie♦ Apr 5 at 17:38

I'm one of those people who wasn't there for it so I don't know about the specifics. By the time I was properly active here the D&D tagging protocols had already been pretty much sorted out.

### The Rolemaster tags

The Rolemaster system involves [a lot of editions and offshoot material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolemaster#History) (first edition was 1980, fourth edition was 1999). Its fans use "RM2" colloquially to refer to first and second edition material, which the [rolemaster-rm2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rolemaster-rm2) tag wiki excerpt clarifies. That works for the Rolemaster community, so it's good enough for us. That tag was originally just [rm2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rm2) but worked its way into [rolemaster-rm2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rolemaster-rm2) instead to clarify it's a Rolemaster tag.

The [rolemaster](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rolemaster) tag refers to the whole series. There's also [rolemaster-fantasy-roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rolemaster-fantasy-roleplaying) and [rolemaster-standard-system](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rolemaster-standard-system).

If the Rolemaster players here feel like it needs to be sorted out a bit further or they need some standardisation, that's up to them and they're welcome to discuss it here on Meta to figure it out. But the way it currently is working is OK per site protocols (specifically the default "tag it however" protocol ), and appears to work for Rolemaster players well enough, so it doesn't need any specific intervention right now.

Comment: Why not [tag:rolemaster-2] instead?

Comment: @okeefe Apparently the term is specifically "RM2", and "rolemaster-2" wouldn't be that term.

Comment: Well, that's different!

Comment: @okeefe Yeah. Along the way of the tag reaching this stage, it started as "rm2", then I edited it to "rolemaster-2e" (which was in hindsight not correct), and it was re-edited into "rolemaster-rm2". I guess it complicates things a little bit when RM2 refers to 1e + 2e simultaneously?